# Query SQL Sum of Value Total Time between StartDate and EndDate Parameter

Tags: c#, database, database-design, sql-server-2012

Good Day!

I have some detail column (table a) like this

```
ID    DateStart        DateEnd        Name    TotalActivity(h)
 1    2018-11-10       2018-11-25     LSA     24
 2    2018-11-11       2018-11-26     LCE     19
 3    2018-11-12       2018-11-27     LSA     24
 4    2018-11-13       2018-11-28     LCE     17
 5    2019-11-14       2019-11-29     LSA     18
```

how can I make the summary column (table b) based on parameter StartDate year = 2018, if I expect the result like below :

```
ID   Name    TotalHour(h) TotalDay(Float)
 1   LSA     48           2
 2   LCE     36           1.5
```

and read about SUM and Datediff, but the difference in here, there are Parameter StartDate and EndDate?

Thank you so much for helping me again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select SUM(TotalActivity) as TotalHour, Sum(TotalActivity)/24.0 as TotalDays 
from tableA where YEAR(DateStart)=2018  group by YEAR(DateStart)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT tablea.ID,tablea.Name, SUM(`TotalActivity(h)`) as `TotalHour(h)` ,SUM(`TotalActivity(h)`/24) as `TotalDay(float)` FROM `tablea` WHERE DateStart LIKE '2018-%' GROUP BY Name ORDER BY ID ASC
```

this is work

[image]